# create mappings with default timestamp doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp

I'm trying to create an index with mappings.
I need it to contain default timestamp in each of his documents.
I searched everywhere on the Internet and did exactly what they asked me. but the code does not work.

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/demo-index-new12345" -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d'
{

"mappings": {

        "doco" : {
          "properties" : {
              "test_date": {
                "type":   "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
              },
              "test_status": {
                "type":   "string"
              }
            },
           "default":{
              "_timestamp" : {
                "enabled" : true,
                "store" : true
              }
           }

        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Elasticsearch are you running?  Default timestamps were deprecated in 2.x and removed.  If you need a timestamp field to be on every document, you need to add a field on the mapping, call it "timestamp", or "created" or something.  Then you can do one of two things:

1. Send "timestamp" field with the current date from your app for each document populated.
2. Add an ingest pipeline that your app uses.  Example for setting a date field to the current time with the ingest pipeline: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/accessing-data-in-pipelines.html#accessing-ingest-metadata.  For more information on ingest pipelines, see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html), [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html), and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-pipeline-api.html)